Incremental path (graph theory)
I have the following problem, which I don't know how to solve. Can anyone help me? Algorithm needs to be in $O(n^2 log\ n)$
Input:
A matrix $C[1..n][1..n]$ with the costs of the edges $\{i,j\}$, where $[i][j]=[j][i]$ and $[i][i]=0$.
Output:
A sequence $v[1..n]$ of integers between $1$ and $n$, for which $C[v[i]][v[i+1]] < C[v[i+1]][v[i+2]]$ for all $i < n−1$.

Hint: define a new digraph whose vertices are the edges of the original graph.
